# Why can't I make a search of a unstored field AND keyword field?

Tags: java, search, lucene, indexing, field

I have a lucene application and it work's well, index and search, except when I want to search 1 field unstored AND 1 field keyword (I have only this 2 kind of field), and I use this analyzer:

> Analyzer analyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer("Spanish", STOP_WORDS_SPANISH());
>
> IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(PATH(), analyzer, true);

And I am sure I put the unstored fields and keywords fields in the same lucene document. So I don't know what fail.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your search should use the same Analysis as your indexing did.
As you are using two different analyzers for storage, you need to use similar analysis when searching.
I suggest you use a PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper to properly match fields with their respective analyzers.